# failed to start the x server (your interface). it is likely not set up correctly (Mint)

Tags: xorg, synaptic

I was trying to configure mouse properties following this guide.

I restarted my computer and got this message :

> Failed to start the x server (your interface). It is likely not set up
>   correctly

I have tried many methods including this thread on Linux Mint: *[<SOLVED> Failed to Start the X server](http://forums.linuxmint.com/viewtopic.php?f=46&t=105156)*.

The error in question is :

> Parse error on line 19 of section InputClass in file
>   /etc/x11/xorf.conf.d/50-synaptics.conf "..." is not a valid keyword in
>   this section.

```
Section "InputClass"
Identifier "touchpad"
Driver "synaptics"
MatchIsTouchpad "on"
    Option "TapButton1" "1"
    Option "TapButton2" "2"
    Option "TapButton3" "3"
    Option "VertEdgeScroll" "on"
    Option "VertTwoFingerScroll" "on"
    Option "HorizEdgeScroll" "on"
    Option "HorizTwoFingerScroll" "on"
    Option "CircularScrolling" "on"
    Option "CircScrollTrigger" "2"
    Option "EmulateTwoFingerMinZ" "40"
    Option "EmulateTwoFingerMinW" "8"
    Option "CoastingSpeed" "0"
    Option "FingerLow" "35"
    Option "FingerHigh" "40"
    ... //line 19 I assume 
    EndSection
```

I am currently locked out of my desktop. It blue-screens and shows the above message.

There is nothing in `/etc/share/X11/xorg.conf.d/50-synaptics.conf`

What can I do to fix this ?

Comment: And what would be in your /etc/x11/xorf.conf.d/50-synaptics.conf ?

Comment: You could just try to remove that `...` with `vim`/`emacs` editor for example

Comment: Can  you explain how you would do that? I'm new to linux. Thanks

Comment: You have a typo in your commands. It's not `x11` but `X11`, and it's not `xorf` but `xorg`. In `vim` you go to the line 19 and delete it with `dd` command; then `ZZ` command saves and quits from the editor

Comment: Please see edit.

Comment: @downvoters - when downvoting, provide information why you downvoted, so that question can be improved.

Comment: First you listed your `50-synaptics.conf` then said that it's empty. Could you please be more consistent and provide correct information?

Answer (score 0):

To edit file:

```
sudo nano -w /etc/x11/xorg.conf.d/50-synaptics.conf
```

Go to the beginning of the line with ... :

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>k</kbd>

to delete whole line, or use backspace like in Notepad.
Now to exit:

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>x</kbd>

Answer questions asked to you(if you want to save, and where - mostly pressing Y and enter).

PS. If you can't do anything(you don't have an access to terminal), try pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>F4</kbd>. You will land in other tty. Log in there with your username and password, run command I gave you, and then try restarting.

Comment: As mentioned above, there's a misspelling. The correct path should be `/etc/X11/xorg.conf.d/50-synaptics.conf`.

Comment: Well, I also tend to fail at spotting typos. :)